# accessing url parameter in react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I declare my route like this:

```
<Row>
  <Route exact path="/services" render={() => <RoutesList {...this.props} />} />
  <Route exact path="/services/new" render={() => <AddRoute {...this.props} />} />
  <Route exact path="/services/edit/:id" render={() => <AddRoute />} />
</Row>
```

Then in some part of my code i create a link like this :

```
<Link to={`/services/edit/${record.id}`}>Edit</Link>
```

in `<Route>` I can see the id in math.params but in `<AddRoute>` I cant access this the url parameter even when I pass the `{...this.props}` for example `<AddRoute {...this.props}>` I cant see the url parameter and match is empty.
my packages is :

```
"react-router": "^4.1.1",
"react-router-dom": "^4.1.1",
"react-router-redux": "^5.0.0-alpha.6",
```

Comment: Maybe you need to provide the parameter name in the url segment. (/:id)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The props of the component that renders your jsx code above does of course not contain the match object. How could it? See the example in the [docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/render-func) on how to pass props to a component in the inline render function:

```js
// convenient inline rendering
<Route path="/home" render={() => <div>Home</div>}/>

// wrapping/composing
const FadingRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route {...rest} render={props => (
    <FadeIn>
      <Component {...props}/>
    </FadeIn>
  )}/>
)

<FadingRoute path="/cool" component={Something}/>
```

The inline `render()` function get's passed the three route props `match`, `location`, `history`. You have to pass the props that your arrow `render()`function receives to your component. Than you will be able to access `this.props.match.id` in your `AddRoute` component:

```js
<Row>
  <Route exact path="/services" render={() => <RoutesList {...this.props} />} />
  <Route exact path="/services/new" render={() => <AddRoute {...this.props} />} />
  <Route exact path="/services/edit/:id" render={props => <AddRoute {...props} />} />
</Row>
```

Also you shouldn't always pass all props to child components. If your `AddRoute` component is only interested in the `id` than you should only pass the id:

```js
<Route exact path="/services/edit/:id" render={props => <AddRoute id={props.match.id} />
```

That may also apply to you other components where you spread `this.props`. Only pass props that are relevant to the component or you will end up with a big mess that is very hard to debug.